# Java Rest : 400. The request is badly formed : URL contains -> api/Components(848569)/Properties('Stakeholder|Application Manager')

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection, patch

My URL is:

```
https://te.avolutionsoftware.com/api/Components(848569)/Properties('Stakeholder|Application Manager')
```

When i am using

```
    allowMethods("PATCH");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String auth = bearerToken;
    //byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String authHeaderValue = "Bearer " + new String(auth);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
    //conn.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
    
    conn.setRequestMethod(method);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String input = data;//"{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(input.length()));
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();
```

Always give

```
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD><BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2><hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
```

My JSON body:

```
 {"Value": "Update Test"}
```

Same java method working fine for "POST" with different URL.

URL working fine in Postman with Patch and same Json Body String.

Any suggestion what could be issue here

Comment: Special characters (`(`, `)`,`|`,etc) in the URL must be escaped. Have you done it?

Comment: No, Not sure How? Checking

Comment: When copied in address bar i got ---> 
| -> %7C
Space -> %20

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: It worked changing Pipe and Space only. Kindly mention it in answeer